# Duplicate class error when using debug and release library in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a library in which I have debug and main packages like so:
debug - `Android/implementation/src/debug/kotlin/myclass/DebugClass.kt`
main - `Android/implementation/src/main/java/some/other/folders/MainClass.kt`

the Debug class looks like so:

```
import some.other.folders.MainClass

class DebugClass: MainClass() {
  ...
}
```

When I put 2 variations of my library into my app:

```
debugImplementation("my-library-debug")
releaseImplementation("my-library")
```

I get `Duplicate class error` for `...MainClass.kt found in (both debug and release implementation)`

Tried combo of invalidate cache/restart/clean build

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out, the issue was actually transitive dependency from  the third library. So it wasn't a conflict between debug and main, but a conflict between debug and third party's main version of the library